# two commands are not running on browser please find the problem?

Tags: javascript

two commands below are not running on browser.......anybody please findout the problem........

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JAVASCRipt">

var myVariable="my name is sonia";

document.writeln(myVariable.big());
document.writeln(myVariable.blink());
document.writeln(myVariable.bold());
document.writeln(myVariable.fixed());

<!-- the following two lines have problems -->
document.writeln(myVariable.fontcolor(“red”));
document.writeln(myVariable.fontsize(“18pt”));

document.writeln(myVariable.italics() );
document.writeln(myVariable.small());
document.writeln(myVariable.strike());
document.writeln(myVariable.sub());
document.writeln(myVariable.sup());
document.writeln(myVariable.toLowerCase());
document.writeln(myVariable.toUpperCase());
var finalString = myVariable.bold().toLowerCase().fontcolor("red");
document.writeln(finalString);
var newvar=myVariable.split('');
document.write(newvar);


</script>
```

Comment: Are you using the correct double quotes?

Answer (score 1):

it looks to me that you used some wrong double quotes in there. such code works as need

```
document.writeln(myVariable.fontcolor("red")); 
document.writeln(myVariable.fontsize("18pt"));
```